# Db2 merge from jdbc with dynamic values

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, merge, db2

I would like to use the db2 merge statement submitting it as a statement from jdbc.
I am in the following scenario. I'm working with a proprietary persistence layer and I'm handling an entity I don't know whether it's already persisted or not and I would like to use the merge statement in order to insert or update a row on the database.
Is it possible?
Suppose I'm working with the table *people* with three columns: *id, name, surname* and I'm handling an entity with id="5", name="chuck", surname="norris" Am I able to issue:

```
MERGE INTO people AS t
  USING (select '5' as id, 'chuck' as name, 'norris' as surname from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)As s
    ON (t.id = s.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET t.name=s.name, t.surmane=s.surname
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
      (id, name, surname)
    VALUES (s.id, s.name, s.surname)
```

such a statement? I'm trying to do that but I got an error. I don't think it's allowed to use a select after *USING*:

```
USING (select '5' as id, 'chuck' as name, 'norris' as surname from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)As s
```

I also tryed to do:

```
USING VALUES('5','chuck','norris') AS s(id,chuck,norris)
```

but it dosn't work. Any help would be appreciated. 
Besides, does anybody know if it's possible to use such a statement in a prepared statement, replacing the real values expressed into the USING part with '?' placeholders in order to set them to the prepared statement using the setXXX() methods?

Thanks

Thanks
Fil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for `MERGE` for your data would be something like this, assuming you're using DB2 Linux/Unix/Windows (LUW).  The `VALUES` clause goes *inside* the parenthesis for the USING part.

Also, if you are using LUW, you cannot dynamically prepare a `MERGE` (I.E., your query can't have parameter markers) in LUW 9.5 or less.  This was added in LUW 9.7.

```
MERGE INTO people AS t USING (
      VALUES (5, 'Chuck', 'Norris'),
             (6, 'John', 'Smith'),
             (7, 'Abraham', 'Lincoln')
             -- maybe more rows
    ) AS s (id, name, surname)
    ON t.id = s.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET t.name=s.name, t.surname=s.surname
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (id, name, surname)
                VALUES (s.id, s.name, s.surname)
```

However, your actual problem with the fullselect may be that you have some typos in your query... for example "surmane" in `UPDATE SET t.name=s.name, t.surmane=s.surname`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked...apparently there were an issue with parentheses...the right USING was the one you wrote! :)